# Use sling models to get data from a backend service

Tags: java, servlets, aem, sling

I've got a servlet extending SlingAllMethodsServlet that is requesting data from a back-end service and is currently sending a JSONObject back in the response object. I would like to utilize SlingModels. Can this be done making use of the servlet I've created or do I have to place all of my servlet code into the activate method of the SlingModel class? If it is possible, could you provide an example?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Am I right to understand that you want to reuse the same data that the Servlet returns in the HTTP response in a Sling Model?

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you describe would be served well by encapsulating the calls to your back-end service as well as associated logic in an OSGI service.  In this way the service can be `@Reference`d by your Servlet and `@Inject`ed by your Sling Model class.

The work of the Servlet would then be reduced to calling the appropriate method on the referenced Service and serializing the return value as JSON.  Similarly the work of the Sling Model would be reduced to calling the appropriate method on the injected Service and exposing the return value to HTL/JSP/whatever in a getter.

Answer (score 0):

What sling models do is gives you the ability to create a small bean that represents a specific Sling Resource.
For example, you might have some resources that have a title and a text. Then you can simply write a Sling Model called TitleTextModel that injects those properties into a bean:

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public class TitleTextModel{

  @ValueMapValue
  private String text;

  @ValueMapValue 
  private String title;

  public String getText() {
      return text;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
      return title;
  }

}
```

If you want to use something like that from your Servlet, you just need to obtain the appropiate resource and adapt it to your model class:

```
TitleTextModel myModel=resource.adaptTo(TitleTextModel.class);
```

Comment: I'd implement interfaces if possible as illustrated here: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#source. With Java 8 `default` methods mixins can be implemented very easily which allows for easier testing compared to the mocking generally required and ensure optimal code reuse.